# How do I clean a service's response when it is illegal XML?

Tags: xml, wcf, soap, .net-4.0

So I believe I understand the concepts and I THINK I should be using an `IClientMessageInspector` but it appears to me that all tools I have to work with the body of a `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message` requires using XML objects within .NET which I cannot do because, well, this message's body is illegal XML. Ultimately, the message is something like this:

```
[random number]
<validXml />
[other random number]
```

for example:

```
379
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <ns1:getVersionResponse>
   <ns1:getVersionResponse xsi:type="xsd:string">1.2.3</ns1:getVersionResponse>
  </ns1:getVersionResponse>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
0
```

Here is an example that would work except for the fact that the above is invalid XML (exactly the reason I'm doing this in the first place!):

```
public class CleanRandomNumbersInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        const int tenMegabytes = 10485760;
        var buffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(tenMegabytes);
        var copyToRead = buffer.CreateMessage();
        string body;

        using (var reader = copyToRead.GetReaderAtBodyContents())
        {
            body = reader.ReadOuterXml();
        }

        // Now that we have the text, modify it
        body = body.Trim('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0');

        // Shove it back into the message
        var copyToPassOn = buffer.CreateMessage();
        using (var stream = GenerateStreamFromString(body))
        {
            var writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(stream);
            copyToPassOn.WriteBodyContents(writer);
        }

        // Implement this method to inspect/modify messages after a message
        // is received but prior to passing it back to the client 
        Console.WriteLine("AfterReceiveReply called");
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        // GNDN
        return null;
    }

    private static Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(s);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream;
    }
}
```

Ultimately, yes, I know, this is a bad service. However, I NEED to consume it nonetheless before the other party fixes this. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using a custom message encoder (wrap the original encoder, and in the implementation of `MessageEncoder.ReadMessage` you'd remove whatever extraneous bytes prior to handing the body over to the original encoder).

But is this really bad XML? This looks like a chunked transfer encoding (see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html, section 3.6.1) - check the HTTP headers to see if you find a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header, then it's up to the HTTP transport to remove those chunks. The HTTP transport in WCF can deal with those, where are you seeing this problem?

Comment: Hmm, you're onto something here. Indeed, that header is there. What I'm seeing is that despite XML (with these extra bits) being returned by the service, my proxies always give me a NULL object being returned by the service methods instead of any kind of object. I manually generated the proxies without much flair (`svcutil http://service.url?wsdl /l:cs /config:my.config`). When I began investigating WHY my responses were always NULL, "invalid XML" was my conclusion. So I guess it's time for me to go back and investigate why my proxies always return NULL...

Comment: For what it's worth, I believe this third-party web service has some screwed-up namespaces. Ughh.....

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to be able to do it inside of your .Net application without completely bypassing the APIs.

My suggestion would be to write yourself a small helper proxy service for this web service, which loads it, strips off the garbage, and outputs the valid XML.

Then your main app will be able to read it from your proxy server as a normal XML SOAP service and wouldn't need to know anything about the bad code they're sending.

And then when they do fix the service themselves, you can simply change the URL in your application back to the original one, and switch off your proxy; no code changes required in your main app, but also no redundant code left behind in it afterward.

Comment: Well, the trouble is that the APIs (at least the ones I've used) take the service URL, and give you the formatted data without your code ever getting to see the actual XML string. So you don't get the opportunity to tweak the XML string prior to it being validated and parsed.